# Add a background to each word in the react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a problem with a react that I can not solve, I have a list of sports categories that I like, and I want to return them in a similar way:

I found [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITl0g.png) on the internet, which reflects my desired output

This is what I tried so far, it did not work for me.

**React Code**

```
const SportFav = ({ categories }) => (
    <div>
        <div className="fcontactinfo">
            <div className="categories">
                {categories.map((s, i) => <div className="fsubcategory">{s}</div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

class Test extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="page">
                <SportFav
                    categories={["running", "swimming" , "tennis"]}
                />

            </div>
        );
    }
)
```

**Sass Code**

```
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.fcontactinfo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    .categories {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        .fsubcategory {
        display: block;
        flex: 1;
        background-color: #34d;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 5px;
        color: #444;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems similar to [badge](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/badge/) except border radius.

Comment: in React use `className` instead of `class` in components

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I just want to use css without bootstrap

Comment: You're mapping on `subcategories` rather than `categories` - not sure if that's a typo in your question or in your code but that would cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I fixed it, but it still does not work for me, I do not understand why.

Comment: Can you include any errors or the exact problems you're having? Are you having a problem with styling or perhaps a console error? Would help to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```js
const SportFav = ({ categories }) => (
  <div>
    <div className="fcontactinfo">
      <div className="fsubcategories">
        {categories.map((s, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="fsubcategory">{s}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div className="page">
      <SportFav categories={["running", "swimming", "tennis"]} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.fcontactinfo .fsubcategories .fsubcategory {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**React**

When you are using `map` inside components, you need to assign an *ID* to the key property, something unique as the index or some unique property of your items.

```
const SportFav = ({ categories }) => (
  <div>
    <div className="fcontactinfo">
      <div className="categories">
        {categories.map((s, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="fsubcategory">
            {s}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <SportFav categories={["running", "swimming", "tennis"]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**SCSS**

To prevent the content from leaving the component when it has a rounded border you should use something more constant in the `border-radius` like px, rem, em, etc. To center you need to add `justify-content` (horizontal-alignment) and `align-items` (vertical-alignment) you can't use them with `display: block` so I changed it to `display: flex`.

```
.categories {
    display: flex;
    .fsubcategory{
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      background-color: #E6E6E6;
      border-radius: 20px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 5px;
      color: #444;
    }
  }
```

If you want margin, add `gap` and `padding` to the "categories" class with equal values.

The final result will look something like this: [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-scss-forked-yuljs?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview)